# Upload file by drag and drop component of Ant design doesn't work in Modal

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, browser, drag-and-drop, antd

I want to create a Modal component to upload a file by drag and drop.

I tested the upload file with the drag-and-drop component outside the modal and the drag-and-drop part works fine.

However, when I put the upload file with the drag and drop component inside a modal, the drag and drop part doesn't work as expected. The file was uploaded to the browser instead of uploaded to the component. The onDrop function was not called.

Here is the modal component with the drag-and-drop component inside.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import type { UploadFile, UploadProps } from "antd";
import { Button, Col, Modal, Row, Upload, message } from "antd";
import { lang } from "../../config/i18n.config";
import { PrintIcon } from "../../components/Icon";
import { PRIMARY } from "../../constant";
import { InboxOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

interface IUploadModal {
  isModalOpen: boolean;
  handleSubmit: (e: any) => void;
  handleCancel: (e: any) => void;
}
const { Dragger } = Upload;

export const UploadModal: React.FC<IUploadModal> = ({
  isModalOpen,
  handleSubmit,
  handleCancel,
}) => {

  const props: UploadProps = {
    name: "file",
    multiple: true,
    action: "https://run.mocky.io/v3/435e224c-44fb-4773-9faf-380c5e6a2188",
    onChange(info) {
      const { status } = info.file;
      if (status !== "uploading") {
        console.log(info.file, info.fileList);
      }
      if (status === "done") {
        message.success(`${info.file.name} file uploaded successfully.`);
      } else if (status === "error") {
        message.error(`${info.file.name} file upload failed.`);
      }
    },
    onDrop(e) {
      console.log("Dropped files", e.dataTransfer.files);
    },
    progress: {
      strokeColor: {
        '0%': '#108ee9',
        '100%': '#87d068',
      },
      strokeWidth: 3,
      format: (percent) => percent && `${parseFloat(percent.toFixed(2))}%`,
    },
  };

  return (
    <Modal centered title="Basic Modal" open={isModalOpen} onOk={handleSubmit} onCancel={handleCancel} style={{maxWidth: "420px"}}>
      <PrintIcon width="53" height="50" color="#0A6EE1" />
      <div className="text-title">{lang("common.print")}</div>
      <div className="text-detail">
        {lang("performance-appraisal.please-select-the-document")}
      </div>
        <Dragger {...props} style={{marginBottom: '3vh'}}>
          <p className="ant-upload-drag-icon">
            <InboxOutlined />
          </p>
          <p className="ant-upload-text">Click to upload or drag and drop</p>
          <p className="ant-upload-hint">Only file XLSX</p>
        </Dragger>
      <Row gutter={[16, 16]} className="button-row">
        <Col span={12}>
          <Button
            type="default"
            onClick={handleCancel}
            style={{ width: "100%", height: 48 }}
          >
            {lang("common.cancel")}
          </Button>
        </Col>
        <Col span={12}>
          <Button
            type="primary"
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              height: 48,
              background: PRIMARY,
            }}
            htmlType="submit"
            disabled={false}
          >
            {lang("common.confirm")}
          </Button>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

I couldn't figure out why the drag and drop is not working when it's inside the Modal component. Anyone had this problem before, or know the reason?

I tried taking out the  component, and only use the  component and it works just fine. The upload button also works normally in every case.

I also tried adding e.preventDefault() inside onDrop function in the drag-and-drop component as well as outside the component, it still does the same thing.

[Modal with Drag and drop upload file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFWN7.png)